# Alternatives to Compute Pole of Inaccessibility in Python?

Tags: python, geometry, software-recommendations

I discovered the other day that Shapely's current implementation of the polylabel algorithm for approximating a polygon's pole of inaccessibility does not always produce a point within the polygon.

Steps to reproduce the problem (from [#1383](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1383)):

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import polylabel


polygon = Polygon([
              (-122.40941047668457,
              37.803324714248184),
              (-122.4094319343567,
              37.8026635004523),
              (-122.40610599517822,
              37.80262959189296),(-122.40602016448975,
              37.800188134708165),
              (-122.40488290786743,
              37.800222044388384),
              (-122.40507602691649,
              37.80346034711567),
              (-122.40941047668457,
              37.803324714248184)
            ])

point = polylabel(polygon, tolerance=1)

print(point)
```

[image]

How can I compute poles of inaccessibility with shapely, ensuring the point is always within the polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@user2856 commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463773/alternatives-to-compute-pole-of-inaccessibility-in-python#comment757378_463773), the issue with `polylabel` producing a point outside of the polygon stems from using a `tolerance` parameter that is too large. A key piece of the puzzle was posted [here](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/discussions/1854#discussioncomment-6515834) - clarification that the tolerance is an absolute value expressed in the units of the given geometry. If this is in degrees, the default `tolerance=1` corresponds to a significant distance. Reprojecting the geometries such that a tolerance could be specified in meters allowed me to produce accurate estimates of the poles of inaccessibility within all of the geometries I needed to process.